# Transport layer on OpenLayers 3 map: ol.layer.OSM is not a constructor

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, layers, tiles, transportation

I'm using the Thunderforest Transport map and I want to overlay it onto my OpenLayers 3 map. After looking through the documentation and following their example (http://www.thunderforest.com/tutorials/openlayers/), I get the following error:

```
ol.layer.OSM is not a constructor
```

Everything in my code is working fine, but the following section raises this error:

```
var transport = new ol.layer.OSM("TransportMap", ["https://tile.thunderforest.com/transport/0/0/0.png?apikey=MY_API_KEY"]);
map.addLayer(transport);
```

I looked at the documentation (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.html) and it seems that OSM is no longer present in ol.layer. What method do I use to add such a layer to my existing map? Should I add it as a Tile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from the Thunderforest website was made for OpenLayers2.

For OL4, I think you should use `ol.layer.Tile` with `ol.source.XYZ`, such as in this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz.html).

```
 new ol.layer.Tile({
       source: new ol.source.XYZ({
               url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' +
                   '?apikey=Your API key from http://www.thunderforest.com/docs/apikeys/ here'
          })
     })
```